# Удаление до создания и другие косяки миграции

Tags: дефект, закрытие-вопросов, миграция, удаление-ответов

[Встретил](//ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/157908) я тут [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/305768/178988), у которого в заголовке есть `[Закрыт]`, хотя сам вопрос не закрыт:

> Линейный список: удаления [Закрыт]

Сейчас такие заголовки делать нельзя...

А потом я заглянул в ответы... и нашёл [такой](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/305775/178988):

[image: скриншот ответа]

Он написан в `2014-03-19 16:34:18Z`, а удалён в `2014-03-19 09:40:02Z` - за 7 часов до написания и не указано, кем именно. Заглядываем в историю, а там удаления вообще нет:

[image: скриншот истории ответа]

А вот в [таймлайне](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/305775/timeline) есть, хотя и не в том разделе:

[image: скриншот таймлайна]

Что за магия?)))

Comment: Специальная <s>уличная</> миграционная магия... нечему тут удивляться, когда можно и репу за принятие ответов на чужой вопрос получать.

Comment: Можно еще обратить внимание на юзера [Deleted](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/7905/deleted?tab=topactivity) с овер 10к правок. Это кажется какой-то брат Виталины. Там, где они наследили, всё может быть довольно странно.

Comment: Всё-таки [не совсем брат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/344259/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D0%B2-ubuntu#comment344277_344259).

Comment: Артефакты минувшей эпохи, не иначе.

Comment: @Nofate но хвосты хорошо бы подчистить.

Comment: @alexolut руками в базе дату поменять?

Comment: @Nofate замутить скрипт, который всё это фиксанёт по всей базе по всем известным косякам.